# ajax timeout google compute engine vm

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a modest Google Compute Engine vm:

```
2 CPUs
7.5Gb
ubuntu 16.x
default network
default subnet
http, https
```

It runs a MySql database, Apache Tomcat and a JXF/Spring based web service that sends data to javascript client

The client accesses the web service using ajax calls.

The timeout set on the ajax call is 10sec, which was fine when I was hosting this with a hosting company.

Now that I've moved this to Google Compute Engine, I'm repeatedly getting timeouts on the ajax calls and i'm not quite sure what to do about it.

What are my options via Google Compute Engine?

If any of you have faced a similar problem, how have you gone about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

The first step I would take would be to figure out how far the ajax call gets before timing out.  Is it able to connect?  Is the request received at the GCE VM?  Is the response sent from the GCE VM in a timely fashion?  How long does it take to transfer the headers of the response?  The body?

If you can get packet captures on the client device, this would be helpful.  In addition, I'd recommend getting packet captures on the GCE VM - perhaps limiting the filter to a particular client that's under your control and where you can observe timeouts as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

This was a misconfiguration of the server.

RTM.  It's in there.